# Exception in Authentication Framework WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am running WSO2 IS 5.0.0. I have the SP for IS 5.0.0 applied along with all the other security patches issued for that version for Identity Server and Carbon 4.2.0. My environment consists of 4 machines that are creating a cluster (using the WKA membership scheme and Load Balancer(AWS ELB) with sticky session enabled). I am using MySQL(not the default H2 database). The machines on which the IS is deployed are Windows Server 2012 R2 (EC2 AWS machines).
Sporadically I receive the following error in the console log:

```
    ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Exception in Authentication Framework
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultLogoutRequestHandler.sendResponse(DefaultLogoutRequestHandler.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultLogoutRequestHandler.handle(DefaultLogoutRequestHandler.java:131)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:97)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:54)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.servlet.CommonAuthenticationServlet.doGet(CommonAuthenticationServlet.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not quite sure what might be causing this error to occur. It is not critical for my system because I have not noticed that it is causing some kind of troubles or downtime.
However I would like to know whether it is a bug or known issue? If so is there a way to be fixed (or applied a workaround) by updating some configuration files? May be there is some sort of patch that could fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add `log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.application=DEBUG` to `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/log4j.properties` and update the question with debug logs.

Comment: Answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301645/wso2is-5-2-null-pointer-exception-in-authentication-framework

Answer (score 1):

I assume this happens when `relyingParty` is null. Try sending it as a query param of the logout request like this.

```
https://is_host.com/commonauth?commonAuthLogout=true&type=samlsso&sessionDataKey
 =E294FEF4A64BF7E14940E2964F78E351&commonAuthCallerPath=https://is_home.com/
identity/main/logoutsso&relyingParty=SAMLSSOIdentity
```

Comment: Did you try sending `relyingParty`?

Comment: In my case I am passing the following query parameters: commonAuthLogout=true, type=oidc, sessionDataKey=unused. I plan to try it out and send the relyingParty, but in that case what value should I pass? Should it be something like "relyingParty=OpenIDSSOIdentity"? Or it doesn`t matter?

Comment: Use SAML issuer name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am going to apply this query parameter to the code I am using and will monitor the system behavior. Will post the outcome.