# WSO2IS-5.2 - Null Pointer Exception in Authentication framework

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I am using `wso2is-5.2` as a identity server in my project. In my project, first I login in one application (`Suppose ULW is this application`) and using `single sign on`, I am getting login in other application`(Suppose other applications are Data Manager and Data Populater)` also. I am able to logging off from ULW but When I am logging off from *`*Data Manager or Data Populator*`*, I am getting exception -

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitLogoutRequestProcessor} -  Error in retrieving Session Index from ssoTokenId cookie : 3f1d4681-a04d-4a84-a75c-634213b2c3ba 
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-12-23 15:16:22,427] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Exception in Authentication Framework 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.cache.SessionContextCacheKey.hashCode(SessionContextCacheKey.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(ConcurrentHashMap.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.caching.impl.CacheImpl.get(CacheImpl.java:194)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.cache.BaseCache.getValueFromCache(BaseCache.java:158)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.cache.SessionContextCache.getValueFromCache(SessionContextCache.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.util.FrameworkUtils.getSessionContextFromCache(FrameworkUtils.java:632)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultLogoutRequestHandler.handle(DefaultLogoutRequestHandler.java:140)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator.handle(DefaultRequestCoordinator.java:140)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonAuthenticationHandler.doPost(CommonAuthenticationHandler.java:46)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonAuthenticationHandler.doGet(CommonAuthenticationHandler.java:37)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.sendRequestToFramework(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:1040)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.sendToFrameworkForLogout(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:517)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleSPInitSSO(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:381)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:195)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doGet(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:95)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Did you send the sessionDataKey ?

Comment: Yes, I send sessionDataKey.

Comment: hmm im not sure but why does it sends and Single Logout request when you try to log.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a known issue in 5.2.0 and fixed in 5.3.0. See https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-5381

Comment: Is patch available for this issue, Which I can apply on 5.2.0 ?

Comment: Only security patches are issued for public. Wso2 issues other patches only for the paying clients. So you will have to wait till 5.3.0 release which will be out in 1 or 2 weeks.

Comment: @Bhathiya: "Only security patches are issued for public." It this still true? My understanding is that since the introduction of WSO2 Update Manager (WUM) even security patches for productions systems are available for paying clients only. Where can I find security updates for WSO2 products for production systems? Thanks!

Comment: You can use WUM itself to get public security updates. All you need is a WSO2 OT account which is free. https://wso2.com/user/register